# Object does not contain definition for Item_Id and no extension method 'Item_Id' accepting first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#

I am creating the invoice window form app, but I get the error of

> object does not contain a definition for Item_Id and no extension
>   method 'Item_Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

for the following code

```
private void StoreData()
{
    int invoiceID;
   // int Item_Id;
   // int quantity;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\oo\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as InvoiceID;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", subtotal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", totalTaxes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                    //invoiceID = cmd.GetInt32("InvoiceID");
                    invoiceID = (int)reader["InvoiceID"];

            }
        }
        foreach (var item in OrderItems.Rows)
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into InvoiceItem(InvoiceID,ItemID,quantity) values (@InvoiceID,@ItemID,@quantity);";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", invoiceID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", item.Item_Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.quantity);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`OrderItems` is a table name which contain the columns of `inv_Id`, `Item_Id` and `quantity`.

The detail of the question can refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024717/save-order-data-to-local-database)

Comment: What is an OrderItems.Row? You are looping over this collection and each element of this collection should have a property named Item_Id. Could you show the definition of the class that is stored in the Rows collection/list/array of the OrderItems class?

Answer (score 0):

If `OrderItems` is a `DataTable` then the syntax to get one of the fields in a `DataRow` (the class stored in the Rows collection) is (roughly)

```
 item["Item_Id"].ToString()
```

But using this value with `AddWithValue` requires the conversion of the value to the correct datatype.
This means that if the field `ItemID` in `InvoiceItem` is an integer then you need to apply a conversion like `Convert.ToInt32(item["Item_Id"])` (and the same applies to `quantity`

```
foreach (var item in OrderItems.Rows)
{
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert into InvoiceItem(InvoiceID,ItemID,quantity) 
                            values (@InvoiceID,@ItemID,@quantity);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", invoiceID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", Convert.ToInt32(item["Item_Id"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Convert.ToInt32(item["quantity"));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```